# Grids constructor isn't called on add to ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, constructor, initialization

I am developing a Windows phone app, and I have this logic:

I have a chat view, with ListView which contain video or text messages. My video messages are custom controls which implements my IPlayableMessage interface:

```
public class VideoMessage : Grid , IPlayableMessage
{
    public VideoMessage()
    {
        this.Loaded += Loaded;
    }

    private void Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessagePlayer.Sub(this);
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        //Some logic for video play
    }

    public Player MessagePlayer
    {
        get { return (Player)GetValue(MessagePlayerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MessagePlayerProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessagePlayerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MessagePlayer", typeof(Player), typeof(VideoMessage), null);

}
```

This is my interface:

```
public interface IPlayableMessage
{
    void Play(Uri uri = null);
}
```

In the constructor I am calling Sub method with this parameter, which enabls my in the future to play my video message.
This works great, however if I add a new message to my `ListView` (and I see it on the view) the controls constructor isn't called and by that my object is not passing it self to the Player.

Why the constructor and Loaded events are not called when new element added to the `ListView`?

The constructor called thought, as I scroll up and down the `ListView` and it performs its paging....

- After a while I've moved my registration to:

  `protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)`

It reduced the numbers of unregistered grids but it's called several times per object and it's also does not cover a 100 percent of the  items.

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you show how are you adding items to the ListView?

Comment: ListView bound to ReadOnlyObservableCollection which is located in my ViewModel  - I am using Mvvmcross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to add callback to the `MessagePlayer` property and handle operation there?

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MessagePlayerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MessagePlayer", typeof (Player), typeof (VideoMessage), new PropertyMetadata(default(Player), PropertyChangedCallback));

private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
       var control = d as VideoMessage;
       (e.NewValue as Player).Sub(control);
}
```

Comment: I didn't understood why would I do that? My issue is that my custom grid isn't subscribes to MessagePlayer, the MessagePlayer property is fine. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Because PropertyChangedCallback is always launched when MessagePlayer is set. You can be sure that Sub(this); will be launched. I added it to my code above. If it doesn't work, the problem can be somewhere else.

Comment: I don't see Register method override in DependencyProperty which gets callback as a parameter. Is your code runs on Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: Hmm... It seems you are trying to add only  PropertyChangedCallback. You have to add new PropertyMetadata(default(Player), PropertyChangedCallback) as a last parameter of Register method.

Comment: Yep... That's what I am  trying to do... I have only one method in Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty which called Register and no overloads with callbacks...

Comment: I think that you are talking about WPF xaml... It seems to be a slight different on windows phone

Comment: There is no overloads of Register method with callbacks, that's true. Last parameter is PropertyMetadata with callback :). Look at the brackets or just replace your MessagePlayerProperty with mine.

Comment: Ohh, that's right... Sorry. I'll try it out, thank you!

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't solved my problem - newly added items (which didn't get to constructor) the callback isn't called either....

Comment: I needed to perform some changes to my code. But eventually it worked! Thanks